Interpretation of the local Moran's I with few neighbours
When running the tool "Cluster and Outlier Analysis (Anselin Local Moran's I)", the random expected value can be determined by permutation. The values of the relevant neighbors are exchanged according to the number of permutations. In my calculations, I have many features that do not have enough neighbors to perform the corresponding number of permutations. How can I interpret the z and p values in this case?
For example: If there is a feature with 4 neighbors, only 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24 permutations are possible. How does the tool perform 999 permutations in this case?

Its not a random permutation of the neighbourhood structure, its a random permutation of the Z values of all the polygons.
Randomly assign all the Z values to the polygons, then compute Moran's I on the random assignment using the same neighbour structure. Repeat 998 more times giving you 999 Moran's I using random assignment of Z to polygon, and compare with the 1 Moran I from the actual Z values at each polygon.
If there's no spatial autocorrelation in the true Z values and locations, then the true Moran's I should be in the ballpark of the 999 simulations. If its bigger than all the simulations, then you can reject the null hypotheses of no spatial autocorrelation.
At least, that's the conventional way of doing things - if you can point to the ArcGIS documentation that should confirm its not doing anything unusual...
If you only have four polygons in your data set then you can't do 999 different random permutations of the four Z values, so the statistics don't work very well. But you probably have a lot more than that.
